# Is specifying my expenses called a 'declaration'?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Scenario: I do some expenses from my personal money on behalf of my company. At the end of the week/month I present my company with a list of these expenses + receipts, so that I can get my money back.

Are:

1. The act of doing so; and
2. The document specifying all this,

Called a *declaration* in English, or is there a better term?

I'm asking because a declaration has more meanings, e.g. a statement like in the *Declaration of Independence*.

Comment: As a Dutchman, I applaud the fact you actually ask the question. Too often have I seen broken English in company processes and procedures just because people over-estimated their mastery of English (we all speak Englisg verry well!)

Answer (score 1):

(***Answer by OP***)

We eventually went for ***Expense report*** and to ***submit expenses***.

These are also short enough to fit (software) menu items.

Answer (score 0):

The normal meaning of [expense account](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/expense-account) is a financial facility provided by en employer to provide funds for your expenses- in the same way as your bank account could be used to cover your personal expenses.

It is also a reasonable term to use to describe the document on which you record, or **account for**, your expenses. Here is a definition of [account](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/account) that describes this usage.

If you have covered the expenses yourself and then want to reclaim the money from your employee, it can also be called an **expenses claim**. If you have to complete a standard form provided by your company, it's and **expenses claim form**.

So, for the act of preparing your expenses, you can say "doing your expenses" (informal) or "preparing your expense account" (formal). For the document itself you can use, "expenses" (informal) or "expense account" or "expense claim" (formal).